# Clojure - Union two queries from separate databases

Tags: sql, clojure

I am querying two separate databases and want to know how to correctly union the results from both - the SQL keyword UNION prints out along with the query results if I print out the 'joined' statement although if I print out the 'formatted' statement, I simply get lots of commas instead of the data I want returned, separated by commas. The code I have produced already is below, thanks in advance!

```
dbquery1 (str "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE xx")
dbquery2 (str "SELECT * FROM database2 WHERE xx")

joined (str dbquery1 " UNION " dbquery2)
formatted (str-join \, (sort (map :data joined)))
```

The results returned then look like this:

```
({:data "result1"}) UNION ({:data "result2"} {:data "result3"} {:data "result4"})
```

I was expecting:

```
({:data "result1"} {:data "result2"} {:data "result3"} {:data "result4"})
```

Comment: You're working with strings, not with database results. You don't have a map, so when you call (map :data x) on a string you get a list of nil, which you then join. Why are you converting everything to strings? Do the operations you want first, and then convert the data to strings if you need to print it out.

Comment: May I ask why you aren't using UNION in the SQL query then destructuring the result?

Comment: The compiler I'm using requires that the connection details are specified distinctly therefore requiring the queries to be run separately and it also requires the SQL statements to be converted to strings. Thanks

Comment: Okay. So the output tells you exactly what is happening: you are returning two seq from the query functions then you are concatenating the seqs with the word "UNION" between them. You left me guessing right now, but perhaps you can try (read-string): http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/read-string. If all else fails, maybe you can try using Korma, or you will have to roll a function that destructures the seqs and emulates the UNION.

Comment: Ah ok thanks very much, I've never heard of Korma although having giving it a quick glance it looks very useful. I'll give that a go, thanks again!